# Identify and classify the singularities of $\frac{1}{\exp(\frac{1}{z}) + 2}$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, derivatives, complex-numbers, singularity

The title pretty much explains it. I'm trying to answer a question where I'm given a few complex functions and it asks me to identify their singularities, and then to classify any that are isolated.

The one I'm having trouble with is

$$\frac{1}{\exp\left(\frac{1}{z}\right) + 2}$$

I'm pretty sure $z=0$ is a singularity (since the function is undefined here), but I have no idea how to see if there are any others. I know the complex exponential can take any non-zero value - but I have no idea how to solve for $\exp(\frac{1}{z}) = -2$, much less how to classify them.

Your help would be really appreciated!

Comment: basically, my editing amounted to merely preceding the function $\exp(\cdot)$ with a backward-slash `\exp(\cdot)`.  Also, sometimes with fractions, when in parentheses, one can "size the parentheses" by using, as I did in this case, using `\exp \left(\frac 1z \right)`, to get "auto-sizing" of the parentheses to fit what they're enclosing.  Just some pointers in formatting, but you did a fine job, and all was completely clear before I edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, $0$ is a singularity, yes. A non-isolated one.

Besides consider the equation $e^w+2=0$. Its solutions are the numbers of the form $\log2+k\pi i$, where $k$ is an odd integer. So, $\exp\left(\frac1z\right)+2=0$ if and only if $z=\frac1{\log2+k\pi i}$, for some odd integer. These are (together with $0$) the singularities of your function. And suppose that it is clear now why $0$ is a non-isolated singularity. All other singularities are isolated ones. And all of them are simple poles (since they are all simple zeros of $\exp\left(\frac1z\right)+2$).